# Change index style in memoir class

Tags: memoir, indexing

I would like to have a bold letter that accordingly separates the index in memoir. Take a look at this image to illustrate my intention:

[image]

This was taken from the `memoir` document, from which I did not see how to change the style of the index. Any help would be appreciated.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,reqno,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Something about an Index}

I would like to have alphabetic\index{index!alphabetic} headers for all of the index entries. The format\index{index!format} should remain unaffected such that it has items and subitems.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I run this in TeXShop (Mac distribution) using the `LaTeX` compiler, `MakeIndex`, and then `LaTeX` again. This is the second part of the question: Is there anyway that I can make this process easier? I.e. combined with the requirement to update my bibliography, I have to run `LaTeX` > `BibTex` > `MakeIndex` > `LaTeX` > `LaTeX`.

In my actual document, I do have hyperlinks enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Section 17.2 in the manual (`> texdoc memman`) explains how to do this by using an `.ist` makeindex style file. Assuming that you have run LaTeX on `mybook.tex` and this produced raw index commands in `mybook.idx` and you have a makeindex style file called `mybook.ist` then running

```
> makeindex -s mybook.ist -o mybookind.tex mybook
```

will generate `mybookind.tex` containing the sorted index entries.

The `memoir` manual shows an example of a file `memman.ist` which could be used as the style for the manual's index. However your TeX distribution should include a file called `gind.ist` which will give bold letters at the start of each batch of entries. So

```
> makeindex -s gind.ist -o mybookind.tex mybook
```

See also the `makeindex` manual (`> texdoc makeindex`).

Answering your second comment, which I really think you should have made a new question, try creating a simple `sid.ist` file like:

```
% MakeIndex style file sid.ist
% Bold head letters
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}"
% end of file
```

Then

```
> pdflatex mybook
> makeindex -s sid.ist mybook
> pdflatex mybook
```

Ask another question about the efficiency of processing indexes and bibliographies.

Fare you well from a GOM.

Comment: How do I get the `mybook.ist` file? I have the `mybook.idx` and `mybook.ind` files when I run `mybook.tex` with makeindex.

Comment: @Sid You have to create your own `mybook.ist` file. As I said the manual has an example and I suggested using `gind.ist`. Did you try that?

Comment: I ran this command (`make index -s kind.ist -o mybookind.tex mybook`) in terminal, and it generates the file `mybookind.tex`. If I open it, it indeed has the boldface headers, but as enteries it has things like: `\item operatorannihilation\pfill \hyperpage{10}` and ` \item operatorcreation\pfill \hyperpage{10}` which as you can see it combines the `operator` subheader with `annhiliation` and `creation`

Comment: @Sid Nobody really has any idea what you have done. What is in file `kind.ist`? I don't have it. If you want any more help then please supply an MWE showing what you have done. It at least needs to go from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}` and include some `\index` entries. Perhaps you should ask another question.

Comment: Due to autocorrection, what I wrote last was simply gibberish. I simply ran your code which was: `makeindex  -s gind.ist -o mybookind.tex mybook`